# Can I create a partner account from another organization user?

Tags: partner-portal, salesforce2salesforce

I have now a new partner. When trying to create for him his new partner portal account, I found out, that the specific user name is already in use.

Asking him, I found that he already uses salesforce for another organization.

I know about S2S (Salesforce2Salesforce)

- How can I have him as a partner in my organization?
- Should I use S2S and share leads with him?
- what are the security risks here?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue as well - I ended up using our company name in front of the users email address as the user name - the setup looked essentially like this:

User Name: company.user.name@domain.com
Email:  user.name@domain.com

That dealt with it and gave the user an user name that made sense without having to work with S2S or other things that would require additional administrative overhead.

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA